# Is there a limit to demagnification of an image as there is for magnification?

Tags: optics

In making wafers for chips, when using masks and demagnifying to a smaller size, is there any limit to demagnification? For light, a microscope’s numerical aperture and wavelength limitation prevents the level of magnification from becoming higher than a certain level.

Comment: Do you mean magnification or resolution?

Comment: when using optical mask for chips, mask representing circuitry is larger than circuit itself, then using lenses they demagnifying it to smaller region in wafer to make nanometer sized elements

Answer (score 2):

The optical resolution limit is $p = 0.5 \lambda / NA$ for off-axis illumination. The numerical aperture $NA=n \sin \theta$ cannot exceed the refractive index $n$ of the medium (vacuum or sometimes water) below the lens. In principle you can reduce lambda indefinitely.